# Pandas drop_duplicates returns NoneType when inplace=True and doesn't drop duplicates when inplace=False

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from certain dataframe. When I have inplace=True it in fact removes the duplicates and returns NoneType dataframe.

When I set inplace=False the dataframe is not modified even when I assign new variable for it.

This works -> removes duplicates but returns NoneType dataframe:

```
df_output = dw_pbi_data_merged.drop_duplicates(subset=["dataset_id", "end_time"], keep=False, inplace=True)
```

This doesnt work -> doesn't remove duplicates and returns dataframe with all values:

```
df_output = dw_pbi_data_merged.drop_duplicates(subset=["dataset_id", "end_time"], keep=False, inplace=False)
```

The thing is, I need to get empty dataframe as result, it correlates with code below.
I know that I could solve it like this:

```
if df_output is None:
    print("do something")
else:
    print("do something else")
```

But I need to solve it like this, because of my work guidelines.

```
if not df.empty:
    print("do something")
```

I've tried modifying keep="first" and I also tried reset_index() but I still get NoneType dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `df_output` is `pd.DataFrame` or `None`, so need test it by `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(df_output, pd.DataFrame):
     print("do something")
```